# Sentry Dio Integration Not Auto-Collecting HTTP Request Tracing Data in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, httprequest, sentry, dio

I have integrated Sentry and Dio into my Flutter app following the guide provided in the [Sentry documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dart/configuration/integrations/dio/). While I can successfully receive error reports and custom performance tracing data, **I am unable to automatically collect HTTP request tracing results using Dio**, as Sentry's documentation suggests. Despite reaching out to Sentry support and reviewing their responses, I am still unable to resolve this issue.

I followed these steps in my app project and run it on a iOS 16.4 iPhone 14 simulator:

1. Created a Flutter app.
2. Added the following packages to my pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
sentry_flutter: ^7.10.1
sentry_dio: ^7.10.1
dio: ^5.3.3
```

3. Initialized Sentry in my app's main.dart as follows:

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sentry_dio/sentry_dio.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn = '<my dsn>';
      options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
    },
    appRunner: () => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
}
```

4. Created a button in MyApp that sends an HTTP GET request using Dio:

```dart
FilledButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final dio = Dio();
    dio.addSentry();

    final response = await dio.get('https://dart.dev');
    print(response);
  },
  child: const Text('TEST PERFORMANCE'),
),
```

I expected that this code would automatically collect tracing data from the HTTP request I sent. However, it does not work as expected. I appreciate any guidance or insights. Thank you in advance!

---

2023/10/02 **Update**: This problem is simply because I misunderstood the documentation. With assistance from the Sentry support team, I now understand that auto collection corresponds to a **span** rather than a **transaction**.  Spans are not individually listed in the performance dashboard but can be found within the breadcrumbs of an issue or transaction. The [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/tracing/distributed-tracing/) provides a detailed explanation of spans, and a sample code snippet is as follows:

```dart
FilledButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final transaction = Sentry.startTransaction('POST /post_ok', 'http');

    try {
      final dio = Dio();
      dio.addSentry();

      final response =
          await dio.post('http://localhost:3000/post_ok');
      print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      transaction.throwable = e;
      transaction.status = SpanStatus.internalError();
    }

    transaction.finish();
  },
  child: const Text('TEST PERFORMANCE'),
),
```

The result would be like this:

```json
POST http://localhost/post_ok [200]
{
  duration: 0:00:00.041514, 
  reason: OK, 
  response_body_size: 63
}
```

Everything is working out perfectly. Hooray!!!

Comment: We have a similar setup, the http requests appear in the breadcrumbs section of error reports, is that what you want ?

Comment: I expect the requests to appear in the "Performance" -> "Transaction" and get information about how long it takes for the request to complete.  @IbraheemAlyan